# how to find no of attributes in an entity class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

```
 public int getColumnCount() {
            return getClass().getDeclaredFields().length;
        }
    this is the code which return no of attributes of same class,but not anaother class
```

> > In my service class,I want to know the number of attributes of a
> >     particular entity class.
> >
> > I have tried a method,which tells the no of attributes present in the
> >     same class.But i want to know attributes of another class.

could you please help me to reach the requirement.

Comment: Add that method in that other class. And then you can call that where needed.

Comment: Hi Rossi,thank you for spending your valuable time on my question.what ever you suggested is absolutly correct.but i have many entity classes,so insted of writing the same method in all the entity classes,is there any way that takes any entity class and returns no of attributes?

Comment: `getClass()` is defined by `Object`, so all you need is a reference to an instance of any class. I'd just add a `Class<?> entityClass` argument to your method signature, and pass in the appropriate class object whenever I called it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is a modified method of the previuos one.

```
private int getAllAttributes(Object entityClass) {      
        return entityClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields().length;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks a lot jonK,it worked helped me.

```
here is the code.
public int getAttributes() {
        EmployeeDO employeeDo=new EmployeeDO();
        Class<?> e=employeeDo.getClass();
        return getAllAttributes(e);
    }

    private int getAllAttributes(Class<?> entityClass) {

        return entityClass.getDeclaredFields().length;
    }
```